# Sending a file via WebRequest

Tags: c#, http, post, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I need to use C# to send a file to with the content-type of application/octet stream.

I can create an HttpWebRequest like the below:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://test.com");
            request.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/octet-stream");
            //Add file here?

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YAYA");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OH NO MR BILL!!!!");
            }
```

How do I accomplish the addition of the file into my stream?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04b716b3-6b7f-4d41-8b2a-0c509c3fc62c/send-large-files-by-httpwebrequest?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs

Comment: `new Webclient().UploadFile(url, fname);`

Comment: @EZI I need to be able to read the response back. Can you do that with WebClient?

Comment: See what above code returns....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Comment: @JohnKoerner I only need to submit binary, not as a multipart/form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the request stream and then copy from your source stream.

```
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
}
```